# Configuring SSL authentication for WebService (WebApplication Server) using CXF framework and CXFNonSpringServlet

Tags: web-services, ssl, websphere, cxf

At present I am publishing the endpoint with endpoint.publish("relative address",implementor). How shall I add the destination configuration in the bus object for using the SSL mutual authentication using third party certificates.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer but:

you do know that WebSphere has full support for *SSL mutual authentication using third party certificates*.

Using CXF and WebSphere is hard when using SSL.